# My classic editor is showing the commands twice?

Tags: visual-editor

[image: screenshot]

I'm confused here, why is the classic editor, showing **both** the graphical buttons in the editor, and the "text" button in the editor, while i'm in the Visual mode?
If I go to the text "mode", the graphical buttons vill disappear

I'm using this as in the frontend, for users to write, and it might be confusing for them!